# crystal reports prompts for database credentials

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, oledb

Let me lay out the background details first.
I'm using visual studio 2013 to write a vb.net windows forms application to load a crystal report (.rpt) file.  The main report and sub report uses a SQL command from a Pervasive database (through an oledb connection) as shown in the picture below.  For privacy, I've changed the database name to DBNAME.[image]

I installed SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Redistributable 13.02 on the client computer.  Obviously, I have the developer version on my computer.
Everything seems to work just fine when I run the build from my computer (the one used for developement), but when I try to run it on the client computer I get a window like the following:[image]

So a few things to note here:

- On the development computer, this prompt doesn't appear.
- For some reason the database name shows up where the file server name should be
- I never set a username or password, nor have I ever needed one to access this database through the control centre from any computer on
  the network
- no conceivable combinations of usernames and passwords work (including network credentials, windows credentials, and leaving it
  blank)

I've tried forcing the credientials in the viewer form load event

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt

rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "FILESERVER", "DBNAME")
rpt.Subreports("Subreport2").SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "FILESERVER", "DBNAME")
rpt.Load()
```

but it doens't seem to make a difference.  What am I missing?

Comment: This could be a driver issue on the PC you're attempting to run the report on e.g. SQL Server Native Client 10. I found this when I created a few reports and on some newer PCs it was missing so I had to install the driver so the report would run without asking for credentials. Obviously you are using a different driver so not sure if that is the problem but thought I'd make the comment nonetheless.

Comment: It's a good starting point, though I don't know how to find what driver to use or how to go about installing it

Comment: Ok, so I changed the connection in the report from OLEDB (ADO) to ODBC (RDO).  Again, all is well on the development computer, but this time the client computer gives me an error "Failed to open the connection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.  Thanks to Bugs for pointing me in the right direction.  The problem was with the connection type in the report.  Changing the connection to ODBC (RDO) using 'right click > Database > set Datasource location' got rid of the credentials prompt, but instead caused a "Failed to open the connection" error.  From there I looked for differences in the ODBC administrator from the pervasive control centre.  I found that I had a system DSN that happened to have the same name as my database (which is why it confused me).  Creating the DSN on the client computer resolved the connection problem.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Sorry I didn't respond until now.

Comment: no problem, though I'm having a similar problem using an access DB, it keeps pointing to a location on my PC, and I can't figure out how to force it to use My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

Comment: nevermind, I got it   rpt.DataSourceConnections.Item(0).SetConnection(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\db.mdb","", 1)

Comment: I have oledbconnection and crystal prompts credentials in LAN pc and not where server is installed. What do I do?